# set default option in select

Tags: forms, html-select, angular2-forms

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="location" class="form-control" class="selectLocation" [(ngModel)]="nameSelectedVal" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">


                    <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [ngValue]="location.code" [disabled]="location.code==0">
                        {{location.city}}
                    </option>

                </select>

                <p class="selectArrow"><button  [disabled]="disableFlag" routerLink="/my-bookride" class="leftArrow">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button></p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is form which i am using to select the option i need to display Select one city as default option when form is loaded

```
export class locationComponent
 {
      butDisabled: boolean = true;
    disableFlag:boolean = true;;
       private locations: any;
  constructor() {

        this.locations = [
  {
    "code": 0,
    "city": "Select one city"
  },
  {
    "code": 1,
    "city": "Hyderabad"
  },
  {
    "code": 2,
    "city": "Banglore"
  }
];
  this.nameSelectedVal = this.locations[0];
}

onChange($event) {
    if($event!=="0"){
   this.disableFlag=false;
   } else{
   this.disableFlag=true;
   }
}
}
```

This is were i am giving options to be displayed in HTML View 
I have tried using  [ngValue] to set Select one city as default value

Answer (score 0):

Use as it is your HTML :

```
                <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [ngValue]="location.code" [disabled]="location.code==0">
                    {{location.city}}
                </option>


            </select>
```

and inside the TS file assign :
this.nameSelectedVal = this.locations[0].code;

it will work.

Comment: @NikhilaKanumuri Please mark my answer to right, so it will be helpful for other

Comment: i think when u get more than 15 reputations then it will get display